# Can't make two divs scroll together

Tags: html, css

https://codepen.io/hatttfu/pen/WNYagMO

I have a parent container with two scrollable blocks inside, one of which is absolute positioned. It's because I need to make a wrapper with border-radiuses. They both guaranteed to have the same width.

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 18px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.head {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 40px;
}

.container .body {
  border: 2px solid #c4c;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 16px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="head">
    we like it, but a person who isn't familiar with his story may have some difficulty seeing how it would be so fitting, but it's hard to ignore the similarities between this dog and cat.
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    we like it, but a person who isn't familiar with his story may have some difficulty seeing how it would be so fitting, but it's hard to ignore the similarities between this dog and cat.
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to fix it with JS by calculating scrollLeft of one block and assigning this value to another's scrollLeft. It's working but flickering and it feels like it's not a proper solution. Is there a way to make both of them scroll synchronously as one block without JS?

Comment: _" Is there a way to make both of them scroll synchronously as one block without JS?"_ - CSS can not make two completely independent elements "synchronize" their scroll behavior. Can you clarify a bit, what the scenario is here? Will both elements always have the exact same content as in your example here, or is that not a given?

Comment: If the dimensions will always be as static as in your example, then I would simply remove the absolute positioning, and apply `overflow: auto;` on the container, instead of the children. Your "wrapper" could then simply be absolutely positioned above the whole thing.

Comment: @CBroe, Hi, thank you for your comment, both elements will always have the same width. Scenario is that I'm trying to make a huge scrollable table where the top block represents a header, and body of the table need to have a wrapper with border-radiuses.

Comment: Just remove the `overflow` property from the three places where it exists right now.

Comment: @TylerH, thanks for reply. if I remove them all, content will get out of the parent container. If I set  `overflow: auto` only to parent container, then my absolute positioning wrapper will be useless. I have to make wrapper that so while scrolling container or head, wrapper can be scrolled inside.

Comment: @yung_gal It sounds like you don't have a [mcve] of your code in the question, then. When you remove the `overflow` properties from the code in your question, the desired outcome you stated is achieved. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76780179/edit) the question to contain a more complete example of your code, otherwise any suggestions or answers are likely to run afoul of further constraints you have that aren't clear/stated yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An idea can be :

- to have only one `overflow` at container level
- manage the wrapper in
  the body part as a `container::before` element
- the wrapper have a `position: sticky`
- the body and the head a `position: absolute`  to place them vertically

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 18px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.container::before {
  content: ' ';
  border: 2px solid #c4c;
  position: sticky;
  border-radius: 16px;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.body, .head {
  position: absolute;
}

.body {
  top: 15%;
}

.head {
  top: 65%;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="head">
    we like it, but a person who isn't familiar with his story may have some difficulty seeing how it would be so fitting, but it's hard to ignore the similarities between this dog and cat.
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    we like it, but a person who isn't familiar with his story may have some difficulty seeing how it would be so fitting, but it's hard to ignore the similarities between this dog and cat.
  </div>
</div>
```

With background different on container and wrapper just play with `z-index` to allow body to be greater than wrapper `z-index`

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 18px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  background: blue;
}

.container::before {
  content: ' ';
  border: 2px solid #c4c;
  position: sticky;
  border-radius: 16px;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  z-index: 2;
}

.body, .head {
  position: absolute;
}

.body {
  top: 15%;
}

.head {
  top: 65%;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="head">
    we like it, but a person who isn't familiar with his story may have some difficulty seeing how it would be so fitting, but it's hard to ignore the similarities between this dog and cat.
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    we like it, but a person who isn't familiar with his story may have some difficulty seeing how it would be so fitting, but it's hard to ignore the similarities between this dog and cat.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your reply! It works, but if wrapper-block is going to have background color different from container's color or grid layout then it won't work. My bad, sorry, I'll give more clearable description to my question.

Comment: for this you can have a background on wrapper and container and play with z-index` to allow body to be greater than wrapper z-index -> i edit my reply in consequences